# How do I set a variable as the return value of an Oracle SQL statement?

Tags: oracle

I'm using a reporting program in which I give it the SQL statement and the values selected, become the variables. For example in this case I'm trying to determine whether a record already exists or not. If it doesn't, return RecordExists with a value of 0; otherwise 1.

This is much simpler (to me) using SQL Server, but I'm trying to figure out why the below will not work. The syntax error generated suggests I need an "INTO" clause with my `SELECT RecordExists FROM Dual;` line even though I'm not trying to assign a value at that point.

```
DECLARE 
  RecordExists NUMBER;
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO RecordExists FROM Times
 WHERE Times.OrderNumber = '123456789' AND Times.StopSequence = '1';
 IF (RecordExists >= 1)
THEN
 SELECT 1 INTO RecordExists FROM dual;
 SELECT RecordExists FROM dual;
ELSE
 SELECT 0 INTO RecordExists FROM dual;
 SELECT RecordExists FROM dual;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: What are you doing with `RecordExists`? It has to be either `return`ed (if in a function), or declared as an OUT parameter (if a procedure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use something a bit simpler, like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN count(*) > 0 then 1 
  ELSE 0 END 
FROM times WHERE OrderNumber = '123456789' AND Times.StopSequence = '1' ;
```